# Getting an empty array when trying to retrieve data from a one to many relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am working a on a platform that allows student search and get a house. I am trying to implement a feature that allows students rate a agent base on what the agent post so as to reduce and moderate scam on the platform. Even after I established a one to many relationship between User(agent) and AgentRating, I get null when I try to retrieve an agent rating.

AgentRating.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AgentRating extends Model
{
    //
     public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Model
{
     public function ratings(){
        return $this->hasMany(AgentRating::class);
    }
}
```

AgentRatingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\AgentRating;
use App\Http\Traits\AuthUserTrait;
use DB;


class AgentRatingController extends Controller
{
    //
    use AuthUserTrait;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(['jwt.auth', 'forceJson'], ['only' => ['store']]);
    }


    public function store(Request $request, $id){
        $this->validate($request, [
            "rating" => 'required'
        ]);

        $rating = new AgentRating;
        $user = User::find($id);
        $rating->user_id = $this->authUser()->id;
        $rating->agent_id = $user->id;
        $rating->rating = $request['rating'];
        $rating->save();
        dd($user->ratings); // This returns an empty array even though there is a rating saved to the DB.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your `AgentRatingController`.

`$rating->agent_id = $user->id;` line seems wrong.

The `$rating_id` should be auto incremental and not fillable. Isn't?

Also, I recommend you to follow the PSR-12 standard when programming.
I mean, declare the property types, the function returning values and the spaces like:

```php
public function store(AgentRatingRequest $request, int $id): void
{
    AgentRating::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'rating' => $request['rating'],
    ]);

    dd($user->ratings);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @JesusValera. I really appreciate the advice.